# MySQL NDB Cluster on FreeBSD 7.1

Tags: mysql, freebsd, cluster, mysql-cluster

Got a problem with a MySQL Cluster,

All the nodes connect fine to the ndb management node, however when I try to create a table on one of the nodes it returns this error :

```
mysql> use foo;
Database changed
mysql> create table bar (i int) engine=ndbcluster;
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'foo.bar' (errno: 157)
```

I check my nodes, and get this :

```
-- NDB Cluster -- Management Client --
ndb_mgm> show
Connected to Management Server at: X.X.X.X:1186
Cluster Configuration
---------------------
[ndbd(NDB)]     1 node(s)
id=2    @X.X.X.X  (Version: 5.1.34, Nodegroup: 0, Master)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1    @X.X.X.X  (Version: 5.1.34)

[mysqld(API)]   4 node(s)
id=3    @X.X.X.X  (Version: 5.1.34)
id=4 (not connected, accepting connect from any host)
id=5 (not connected, accepting connect from any host)
id=6 (not connected, accepting connect from any host)

ndb_mgm>
```

so all looks good,

heres some version stuff .

```
FreeBSD my.server.com 7.1-RELEASE FreeBSD 7.1-RELEASE #0: Tue May 12 10:12:51 CAT 2009     sysbg@my.server.com:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/SEROTONIN-KERNEL  i386

/usr/local/libexec/mysqld  Ver 5.1.34 for portbld-freebsd7.1 on i386 (FreeBSD port: mysql-server-5.1.34)

MySQL distrib 5.1.34, for portbld-freebsd7.1 (i386) compiled with --with-ndbcluster --with-plugins=max
```

Any assistance will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the cluster. First bring the management node online, then the servers. I think this is a race condition (well sort of). Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for the input, tried rolling restarts to no effect, think I am just going to bite the bullet and use debian for this.

Answer (score 1):

Management node seems fine, but you have no data nodes.  You need to get /usr/sbin/ndbd running correctly on data nodes....why it's not in probably in your my.cnf file.